# Does "git push --set-upstream origin name/of/my/branch" store intermediary branches?

Tags: git, git-branch

If I do `git push --set-upstream origin  name/of/my/branch` will that create any intermediary branches that may exist between itself and master?

e.g. say I branch off my `master` branch to create one called `B1`. I then branch off `B1` to create `B2`. I repeat this from `B2` to `B3`.

Now is there any information about `B1` and `B2` stored remotely (either via a physical branch or in the logs)?

Comment: What do you mean by "intermediary branches"?  Git has no such concept -- branches have no relation to each other, other than remote tracking and common ancestor commits.

Comment: I've updated the text with an example using B1 and B2 as branches off master.

Answer (score 3):

No, branches are fully independent of each other.

They are essentially just pointers to a commit.

`git push --set-upstream origin B3` will push B3 and not B1 and B2 as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could us the shorthand flag "-u"

```
git push -u origin <branch>
```

or in this case:

```
git push -u origin B3
```